# Do these both syntax \\d\\d\\d and \\d{3} work the same in all environments?

Tags: java, regex

Would like to ask is there a difference between these two regular expressions?

`\d\d\d` vs. `\d{3}`

I have tested this in my local machine using java and windows OS and both work perfectly ok and have same result. However when ran in linux environment, `\d\d\d` works ok while `\d{3}` does not. Is the environment a factor here? Or what else could be a factor which make these both expressions differ in result?

here's the snippet of the code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( ".*aaa\\.bbb\\d{3}.ccc\\d{3}." );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( "aaa.bbb033.ccc342.ffff" );
matcher.find();
```

Using `\d\d\d`, matcher.find() = true

using `\d{3}`, matcher.find() = false

Comment: It's not the regex. It was something else.

Comment: Which language? C# .NET?

Comment: They are equivalent regexes. It must be something with the way your are executing it. Please show your test code (exactly). Btw @shiplu, this is clearly java, so I added the java tag.

Comment: As @ikegami points out below, there are many dialects of regex that vary in details of what they will accept.

Comment: [**They are equivalent**](http://ideone.com/wqT51L)

Comment: Thanks guys. i've confirmed that both expressions are equivalent in java. There were just other factors that affected the input that resulted to different output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are different regex dialects.<sup>[1]</sup> `grep` even knows more than one.

```
grep    'abc|def'     # Matches abc|def
grep    'abc\|def'    # Matches abc or def
grep -P 'abc|def'     # Matches abc or def
grep -P 'abc\|def'    # Matches abc|def
```

Good old `grep` (without `-P` or `-E`) simply doesn't recognize `a{m}`. Or `\d`.

```
$ cat foo
123
1{3}
\d{3}
\d\d\d

$ grep '\d{3}' foo
\d{3}

$ grep '\\d\\d\\d' foo
\d\d\d

$ grep '\d\d\d' foo
ddd
```

Though it does in "Perl" mode (and in "Extended" mode in some versions)

```
$ grep - P '\d{3}' foo
123

$ grep -P '\d\d\d' foo
123
```

That said, I would expect all implementation of a given version of Java to understand the same regex language.

---

1. In fact, the regular expression of some languages aren't technically regular expressions by the [original definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) anymore as they can match more than [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Comment: Hi @ikegami thanks for the response. If i understand correctly, both expressions (\\d\\d\\d and \\d{3}) cant be recognized in linux unless in perl mode? What would you suggest to do in order for these both expressions be recognized in both environments (linux and windows)

Comment: Unix grep **understands** `\d{3}` on extended mode. Run `echo -e '123\nab3' | grep -E '\d{3}'` on console to see it in action.

Comment: It has nothing to do with OS. Different tools (`grep` vs `java`) have different matching languages.

Comment: `echo -e '123\nab3' | grep -E '\d{3}'` returns nothing for me.